# PHP website not seeing CSS code (Docker, NGINX, VS Code)

Tags: php, css, docker, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue getting a website I am developing to load any CSS file. I can get the site to load the index.php test, but when I add the include header statement it does not pull in any css files.

Docker-compose

```
services:
  web: 
    image: nginx:latest
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/dfault.conf
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

Docker File

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install
```

The header file (the last line has the link to the path for css file)

```
<?php include 'static_settings.php'; ?>
<??>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $metaKeywords ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metaDescription ?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $metaDescription ?>" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $name ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<? echo $name ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="icon" href="#">
<title><? echo $name ?>| <? echo $title ?></title>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/756891195a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- STYLES -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The index.php file

```
<?
$title = "Home"; 
$metaKeywords = "Home, apartment, living, Glenridge Heights, kitchens, amenities, enclosed garages, storage units, community, neighbors, life, applicances";
$metaDescription = "Glenridge Heights is a gated, swim community of townhomes in Sandy Springs, inside I-285";
include 'header.php' 
?>
<h1 class="text-center">TEST header</h1>
<p>what is going on here</p>

<? include 'footer.php' ?>
```

The folder structure of the site is as follows:

```
app
-css
-js
index.php
header.php
footer.php
```

I have used this in the past and it works, only thing I can think of is that I might need a different PHP engine from docker (php:8.1.0-fpm for example). All help is appreciated

Comment: In your browser's inspection tools, are you getting a 404 for that resource? Can you access the resource directly?

Comment: No 404 error. When you click on sources it just shows the entire header where the css content should be. I also get one console error ```mdb.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at mdb.min.js:1:1))```

Comment: `<? include 'footer.php' ?>` is short tag syntax, is it possible you have it [disabled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)?

Comment: Header and footer statements are included in the same way. I do not have anything disabled. I am a little confused as to why when you click on sources css/custom.css it shows the entire document there. It's like the PHP is registering something. I was thinking that maybe the Apline install I pulled from docker isn't working properly.

Comment: Ok, so if I do a direct CDN URL  for a CSS stylesheet it will load (used bootstrap to test). Not sure if that helps anyone narrow down exactly what the issue is in the config files.

Comment: Can you confirm that the resource is being download in the network inspector? And what mime type is being returned from the server?

Comment: What does the nginx vhost config look like? How is PHP configured in nginx?  How have you mapped the `app/` volume into the nginx container/docroot? It sounds like every request is getting the same PHP response, which sounds like an nginx conf problem to me. Is the PHP actually parsing, or are you just getting the script as text?

Comment: Is that `Dockerfile` really building a working PHP container? I've never seen `docker-php-ext-install` used like that - it is for installing extensions, so would usually have some extensions listed after it, what does using it without any do?

Comment: I realized after the fact it was installing and allowing the port to be open and seen. You are correct it was not actually loading any files and therefore was not creating a real container. I did find this GitHub repository that gives a good clean starter file for anyone else having issues: https://github.com/mhilker/docker-nginx-php-example